# Single SPA integration with server side rendered html pages

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, single-spa

I have an application in which UI is rendered on the server-side using Thymeleaf and the backend is in Spring Boot.

Now, we have a requirement to combine this application with another react application. So, it should be like micro frontend architecture.

For this, I am evaluating the framework Single-SPA and seems like a good option when we have separate frontend projects and we need to combine them in one.

Is it possible to integrate the existing SSR pages with Single-SPA?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible with [single-spa-html](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-html-web-components/) as long as there is no JavaScript that is dynamically created. Another limitation is that single-spa-html doesn't process `<script/>` tags due to browser security. If your application can meet those requirements, it should be able to interop with single-spa-html.

single-spa-html allows providing a template asynchronously, so a fetch or ajax call could retrieve the microfrontend template from the backend. Then the corresponding JavaScript is included in the microfrontend instead of script tagged in.

You can also see an example of enhancing a static html mfe with JS here: https://github.com/filoxo/single-spa-html-with-js-example/

---

Note: I believe we discussed this on the Slack channel but I want to share here for the benefit of the wider single-spa community.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.